# Getting error on clicking Menu icon in Vue 3 admin template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuex

i have installed CoreUI Vue admin template [CoreUI Vue Template](https://coreui.io/product/free-vue-admin-template/). All the code is working fine except for the **menu icon** [image: menu icon].

when i click on it to hide the side bar(it's a built in functionality .) it's not working and giving this error

`[vuex] unknown mutation type: updateSidebarVisible   main.js:17`

`vuex.esm-bundler.js:943 [vuex] unknown mutation type: toggleSidebar`

This below is the **AppHeader.vue** file code where the menu icon is implemented

```
<template>
  <CHeader position="sticky" class="mb-4">
    <!--  eslint-disable  -->
        <CContainer fluid>
            <!-- <CHeaderToggler class="ps-1" @click="$store.commit('toggleSidebar')">
   <CIcon icon="cil-menu" size="lg" />
            </CHeaderToggler> -->
             <CHeaderToggler class="ps-1" @click="toggleSidebar">
   <CIcon icon="cil-menu" size="lg" />
            </CHeaderToggler>
            <CHeaderBrand class="mx-auto d-lg-none" to="/">
                <CIcon :icon="logo" height="48" alt="Logo" />
            </CHeaderBrand>
            <CHeaderNav class="d-none d-md-flex me-auto">
                <CNavItem>
                    <CNavLink href="/dashboard"> Dashboard </CNavLink>
                </CNavItem>
                <!-- <CNavItem>
                                          <CNavLink href="">Users</CNavLink>
                                        </CNavItem>
                                        <CNavItem>
                                          <CNavLink href="">Settings</CNavLink>
                                        </CNavItem> -->
            </CHeaderNav>
            <CHeaderNav>
                <CNavItem>
                    <CNavLink href="">
                        <CIcon class="mx-2" icon="cil-bell" size="lg" />
                    </CNavLink>
                </CNavItem>
                <CNavItem>
                    <CNavLink href="">
                        <CIcon class="mx-2" icon="cil-list" size="lg" />
                    </CNavLink>
                </CNavItem>
                <CNavItem>
                    <CNavLink href="">
                        <CIcon class="mx-2" icon="cil-envelope-open" size="lg" />
                    </CNavLink>
                </CNavItem>
                <AppHeaderDropdownAccnt />
            </CHeaderNav>
        </CContainer>
        <CHeaderDivider />
        <CContainer fluid>
            <AppBreadcrumb />
        </CContainer>
    </CHeader>
</template>

<script>
/*  eslint-disable */
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';
import AppBreadcrumb from './AppBreadcrumb'
import AppHeaderDropdownAccnt from './AppHeaderDropdownAccnt'
import { logo } from '@/assets/brand/logo'

export default {
    name: 'AppHeader',
    components: {
        AppBreadcrumb,
        AppHeaderDropdownAccnt,
    },
    methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['toggleSidebar']),
    },
    setup() {
        return {
            logo,
        }
    },
}
/*  eslint-disable */
</script>
```

This is the code file where vuex implemented **index.js** it's in store folder

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    sidebarVisible: '',
    sidebarUnfoldable: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    toggleSidebar(state) {
      state.sidebarVisible = !state.sidebarVisible
    },
    toggleUnfoldable(state) {
      state.sidebarUnfoldable = !state.sidebarUnfoldable
    },
    updateSidebarVisible(state, payload) {
      state.sidebarVisible = payload.value
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
})
```

This below is the **main.js** file code

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import auth from './auth/auth'
import axios from 'axios'

import CoreuiVue from '@coreui/vue'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-vue'
import { iconsSet as icons } from '@/assets/icons'
import DocsExample from '@/components/DocsExample'

const app = createApp(App)
// app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.use(CoreuiVue)

app.provide('icons', icons)
app.component('CIcon', CIcon)
app.component('DocsExample', DocsExample)

// Access token code
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://your-instance.salesforce.com'

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const accessToken = auth.getters.accessToken
  if (accessToken) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
  }
  return config
})

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // Access token has expired, redirect to the login page.
      // You can also show a message to the user indicating that they need to log in again.
      // Replace '/login' with the actual path to your login page.
      window.location.href = '/login'
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
  },
)
app.use(store)
app.use(auth)
app.mount('#app')
```

Can anyone help me to pinpoint the issue and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In vuex store you have to use state of sidebarVisible type boolean after that may be work fine.

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

export default createStore({
  state: {
    sidebarVisible: false, //hidden by default
    sidebarUnfoldable: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    toggleSidebar(state) {
      state.sidebarVisible = !state.sidebarVisible;
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

Comment: hello @DhruvPatel , i did what you said and did some change in AppHeader.vue 
    methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['toggleSidebar']),
    // toggleSidebar() {
    //     eventBus.emit('toggleSidebar');
    //   },
    },


but it's not working and when i click on the icon giving this error

" [vuex] unknown mutation type: toggleSidebar   vuex.esm-bundler.js:943"